# How to get the console.log content as string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, logging, console

I'm trying to get the console.log as string in pure JavaScript.
My input is a script, which I'm not familiar with, and I want to collect all the messages in the console.log into a string.

For example:

```
function doSomething(){
    console.log("start");
    console.log("end");
    var consoleLog = getConsoleLog();
    return consoleLog;
}

function getConsoleLog(){
    // How to implement this?
}

alert(doSomething());
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/EWWnn/)

Note that I do not need to alert the log - this is just a simple example of testing the functionality. I'll have to do some operations on the log's content.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could overwrite `console.log` method before using it:

```
var logBackup = console.log;
var logMessages = [];

console.log = function() {
    logMessages.push.apply(logMessages, arguments);
    logBackup.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

Using `apply` and `arguments` preserves the correct `console.log` behaviour, i.e. you can add multiple log messages with a single call.

It will push all new `console.log` messages to `logMessages` array.

Comment: This throws a "InternalError: too much recursion" error for me.

Comment: That might be because you are defining console.log more than once

Answer (score 0):

for security issues, there is no api to read the history of console.log().