# Creating another instance of the javascript console

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

Is it possible to create another instance of the javascript console and use it at one's own discretion, such as placing content filed to `console.log()` in a `div` on your page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24059643/4633197), which you could implement by grabbing the value of the stack and writing it to a div on your page.

```
<div id="log"></div>
```

---

```
var logBackup = console.log;
var logMessages = [];

console.log = function() {
    logMessages.push.apply(logMessages, arguments);
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < logMessages.length; i++){
      var pre = document.createElement("pre");
      pre.innerHTML = logMessages[i];
      document.getElementById('log').appendChild(pre);
    }
    logBackup.apply(console, arguments);
};
console.log("My name is joe.")
console.log("My name is tom")
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/7g6kchox/**

Comment: Thank You. You came first, so your answer is accepted – please note though that none of the given answers offer a straight answer to the actual question – whether it's possible to create another `instance` of the console. The approach offered however, does work and is much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at [console profiles](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#profile). Note that this reference is only for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You can override it, but that's not a good practice. Like this:

```js
console.log = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
      document.getElementById("logs").textContent += JSON.stringify(arguments[i], null, 4) + '\n\n';
}


var object = {a: 45, b: "hh"};

console.log(object);

console.log("Hello world!");

console.log(45 + 5);
```

```html
<pre id="logs"></pre>
```

**Note 1:** `console.log` is a great tool for debugging, it should not be overriden. I don't recommend you override it but instead, I'll recommend you make a function (called for example `myConsoleLog`) that does what you need.

**Note 2:** The example I provided is just a basic example to give you insight, you'll need a lot of other stuff (the folding of objects and arrays, the logging of functions for example...).

Answer (score 1):

You can override `console.log`. Something like this:

```
console.log = function(objToLog) {
  var myLog = document.getElementById('myLog');
  var str = '';
  if (typeof objToLog === 'string') {
    str = objToLog;
  } else if (typeof objToLog === 'object') { //includes array print
    str = JSON.stringify(objToLog);
  }
  myLog.innerText = myLog.innerText + '\n> ' + str;
}


console.log('log this line');
console.log('log this other line');
console.log([1,2,3]);
console.log({ key: 'value' });
```

Will *print* to a div:

```
> log this line
> log this other line
> [1,2,3]
> {"key":"value"}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/a08qL18d/